# Is the PK of a DB2 table a clustered index by default?

Tags: sql, db2

This can be a silly question but I want to be sure 100%.

Is the PK of a DB2 table a clustered index by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: **[DB2 docs - Clustering indexes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_clusteringindexes.htm)**

> Although a table can have several indexes, only one index can be a clustering index. If you do not define a clustering index for a table, DB2 recognizes the first index that is created on the table as the implicit clustering index when it orders data rows.

So no, by default the Primary Key is NOT the clustered index of the table.

The first created index, unique or not, is the "implicit" clustering index and DB2 tries to insert the records as nearly as possible in the order of the values of this index.

If you later create another index and identify it as clustering, then DB2 identifies it as the clustering index but **does not rearrange the data** that is already in the table. This can be done with the REORG utility.

Comment: I always wondered what all the hullabaloo over REORGs was around here.  Now I know.  Thanks!  (even if I'm not the OP)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_clusteringindexes.htm) (this assumes DB2 for z/OS, version 9)

> When a table has a clustering index, an INSERT statement causes DB2 to
>   insert the records as nearly as possible in the order of their index
>   values. **The first index that you define on the table serves implicitly
>   as the clustering index unless you explicitly specify CLUSTER when you
>   create or alter another index.** For example, if you first define a
>   unique index on the EMPNO column of the EMP table, DB2 inserts rows
>   into the EMP table in the order of the employee identification number
>   unless you explicitly define another index to be the clustering index.

You can see which index is the clustering index for a table (in this example, `TEST.TABLE1`) using the following query, if you're on z/OS:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES
WHERE TBCREATOR  = 'TEST'
  AND TBNAME     = 'TABLE1'
  AND CLUSTERING = 'Y'
```

And this one for Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW):

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'TEST'
  AND TABNAME   = 'TABLE1'
  AND INDEXTYPE = 'CLUS'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. btw: that query is not working, I get this error `SQL0206N  "CLUSTERING" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703`

Comment: @Luka, then you may be using DB2 on LUW.  I've added a second query that should get you the same info.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't create clustered index for a PK by default.

> Primary keys
>
> A primary key is a special type of unique key and cannot contain null values. For example, the DEPTNO column in the DEPT table is a primary key.
>
> A table can have no more than one primary key. Primary keys are optional and can be defined in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements.
>
> The unique index on a primary key is called a primary index. When a primary key is defined in a CREATE TABLE statement or ALTER TABLE statement, DB2 automatically creates the primary index if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> DB2 is operating in new-function mode, and the table space is implicitly created.
> DB2 is operating in new-function mode, the table space is explicitly created, and the schema processor is running.
> DB2 is operating in conversion mode, and the schema processor is running.
> If a unique index already exists on the columns of the primary key when it is defined in the ALTER TABLE statement, this unique index is designated as the primary index when DB2 is operating in new-function mode and implicitly created the table space.

See at: [Keys DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z.doc.intro/db2z_keys.html)

Comment: This states that an *index* is created for a PK. The question is, it a *clustered index*? That is, does the PK [index] define the physical location of the row data that is not covered by the PK?

Comment: See also: [wikipedia: clustered index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Clustered) and [clustered index](http://sql.wikis.com/wc.dll?SQL~ClusteredIndex) and [DB2 index types](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z.doc.intro/db2z_keys.html)

Comment: Do you see `clustered index` at documentation? then.. DB2 dont create it for a PK by befault...

Comment: @AndersonCarniel: Perhaps you want to add that in your answer (*"DB2 doesn't create clustered index for a PK by default."*)